# Thought experiment using quantum entanglement in position and its effects

Tags: discussion

I had asked a question in physics stack exchange a while back, but never got an answer. It surprisingly was never closed nor anyone had any comments. I feel like people are thinking, "ugh, another superluminal scheme..." and never bothered to even consider it.

Perhaps its more appropriate to ask it here?

[Thought experiment using quantum entanglement in position and its effects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105009/thought-experiment-using-quantum-entanglement-in-position-and-its-effects)

Comment: You can always try to put a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

No, it would not be appropriate to ask this question here on meta. It's not a question about the PSE website.

Without any feedback, I don't think you're justified to make any *assumption* about what people are thinking - the best you can do is speculate, but you never know if your speculation is right without hearing from others. I will say this: the question is a little on the long side, which is not a bad thing (in fact it's of an appropriate length to potentially be a pretty good question) but it does mean only a limited number of people will be willing to read and understand the whole thing.